# 404 Not found error when trying to use javascript file from bootstrap

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I'm new to rails and I am trying to get a website up using start bootstrap, specifically the landing page found [here](https://startbootstrap.com/theme/freelancer). I have imported the css and html into my rails project, but I am having a hard time with the javascript. The script file is in `app/my_app/javascript/packs.` They stylings go in `app/assets/stylesheets` and I can successfully reference the images contained in them using `<img src> assets/stylesheets/...</img src>.` I boot up the server with `rails s` and it loads up in my browser with the relevant style and images albeit without any javascript. The specific error in the console reads

> localhost/:468 GET http://localhost:3000/packs/scripts.js 404 (Not Found)

I reference the script at the very bottom of my index.html.erb page like so

`<script src> packs/scripts.js </script>`. I have also tried `javascript/packs/scripts.js`

My applications.html.erb looks like this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TestApp</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
     <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'styles', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` tag only appears once and in only that file.

My applications.js file is this

```
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require jquery.easing.min
//= require jquery.fittext
//= require wow.min
//= require scripts
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("packs/scripts")
```

So rails/webpacker can't seem to find the script under the `javascript/...` path, and I don't know why. I have scoured and tried alot of solutions but all to no avail. Any help or suggestions on the issue would be supremely appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have a script.js from Webpacker that you want to load in Rails, you can load it using `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'scripts', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`.

`javascript_pack_tag` is a helper method that will automatically generate script tag and url for you.

Additionally, because you're using turbolinks and have added `'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'`, you can place the `javascript_pack_tag` in your `<head>`.

Comment: Hey! Thanks so I took your advice and ended up replacing the <script src> tag with the <javascript_pack_tag> in my index.html.erb file and it works. However I had to take it completely out of application.html.erb. Does this mean that I would have to include it in every single page(if I want those pages to work with that script) that I build?